# Convert number to other type number and thow error when information is lost

Tags: c#, .net

I want convert a number to other type number like :

```cs
var to = System.Convert.ChangeType(from, typeof(T));
// T : destination type.
```

When a big number is converter to little type, it throw OverflowException. But in case decimal to integer, this method round the value :

```cs
var to = System.Convert.ChangeType(from, typeof(42.69));
// to => 43
```

It's behavior explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/type-conversion).

A solution is to convert `from` to string before convert to final type :

```cs
var to = System.Convert.ChangeType(from.ToString(), typeof(42.69));
// System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

This need a intermediate conversion, bad for performance.

Other solution is enumerate all type to prevent decimal->integer conversion, but it's very verbose.

Do you know other elegant solution?

Comment: `42.69` is NOT a decimal type... but a double. You need to add the literal `m` or `M`. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types).

Comment: By decimal, I think `float`, `double` and `decimal` .NET type : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal

Comment: that's just confusing... C# is a strongly-typed language. The types are not the same... especially [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#the-decimal-type) is the odd-one out. It's more of an integer type divided by 100...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the value back and check whether the roundtrip converted value matches the original.

```
var converted = Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(int));
var roundtripValue = Convert.ChangeType(converted, value.GetType());
if (!object.Equals(value, roundtripValue))
{
    throw new Exception("...");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not standardized. If you try to implicitly cast a double/float to an int, you get an error. E.g.

```
double d = 12.34;
int i = d;
```

gives "error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

So you can overrule this by using a explicit cast, or a converter, *just like you are doing*.
Data loss as a result of this explicit conversion is then assumed behavior. There isn't even an exception defined for data loss, so if you want an exception, you will have to make your own.

If you will have to implement this check yourself. You can for instance check for a fraction arithmetically

```
decimal d = 12.34m;
if (d%1 != 0) throw new Exception("Data loss in conversion from decimal to int");
int i = (int)d;
```

Comment: In my case the origin and expected type is unknown, but I get the idea.